# How to count a tree of numbers which the number fit the predicate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

I am trying to define a count function which counts each number in the tree that satisfy the predicate.

```
#given function:
class TN:
    def __init__(self,value,left=None,right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right

def add(atree,value):
    if atree == None:
       return TN(value)
    if value < atree.value:
       atree.left = add(atree.left,value)
       return atree
    elif value > atree.value:
       atree.right = add(atree.right,value)
       return atree
    else:
       return atree  # already in tree

def add_all(atree,values):
    for v in values:
        atree = add(atree,v)
    return atree

def is_prime (x):
    assert type(x) is int and x >= 0, 'predicate.is_prime x is not a positive int: '+str(x)
    if x <= 2:
       return x == 2
    for i in range(2,x):
       if x % i == 0:
          return False
    return True
```

add_all function takes a list and returns a tree.
is_prime function returns True if the int parameter is prime.

```
#function I am trying to define (a recursive function: count):
def count(t,p):
    if t==None:
       return 0
    else:
       return 1+count((t.left if p(t.left.value) else t.right),p)
```

for example,

```
import random
values = [i for i in range(1,200)]
random.shuffle(values
```

)
    ###Calling the count function as following should give me:
    count(add_all(None, values), is_prime) # --> 46

My count function gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I am new to use tree, and I think I am having problem to define my recursive count function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of your `t.left` attributes is `None`. That stands to reason, a binary tree doesn't go on forever.

However, if you are to count all values matching a predicate you'll have to traverse all those elements, not just those that match the predicate. Always traverse the nodes, but only return a count for the nodes that match:

```
def count(t, p):
    if t is None:
       return 0
    result = 1 if p(t.value) else 0
    return count(t.left, p) + result + count(t.right, p)
```

E.g. return the count of the current node (0 or 1) plus the recursive count of the left and right nodes. If either of those is `None` then the recursive function stops and returns `0` for those.

You could even just use:

```
def count(t, p):
    if t is None:
       return 0
    return count(t.left, p) + p(t.value) + count(t.right, p)
```

because in Python, the boolean type is a subclass of `int` where `True == 1` and `False == 0`; summing integers and booleans treats the booleans as integers:

```
>>> 0 + True
1
```